# Select SQL records with blank values

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a stored proc used in SSRS reports which has to return records with blank values for confirmation number field if a blank value is passed or a record with the specified confirmation number if a confirmation number is passed in. It has to return all records if a null value is passed in.

My sql right now is

```
(IsNull(@ConfirmationNumber,'') = '' or RoomRegistration.ConfirmationNumber 
like '%' + @ConfirmationNumber + '%')
```

my above sql query is returning all results when a blank or null value is passed. How do I modify it to return only the records with blank confirmation number when a blank value is passed and return all values when a null value is passed?

I even tried this variation

```
(ConfirmationNumber LIKE CASE WHEN @ConfirmationNumber ='' 
 THEN @ConfirmationNumber WHEN @ConfirmationNumber is NULL THEN '%%'
 ELSE '%' + @ConfirmationNumber + '%' END )
```

still doesnt work the way I wanted..Please advise

Comment: So, @ConfirmationNumber is what is being passed in from the report?  Are you allowing it to actually pass NULL back from the report or are you sending back an empty string ('')?

Answer (score 0):

you where clause should look like so:

```
@ConfirmationNumber is null 
            OR RoomRegistration.ConfirmationNumber like '%' + @ConfirmationNumber + '%' ) 
            OR (IsNull(RoomRegistration.ConfirmationNumber, '') = '' AND @ConfirmationNumber = '')
```

Been awhile though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`( ConfirmationNumber LIKE CASE WHEN @ConfirmationNumber ='' 
 THEN @ConfirmationNumber WHEN @ConfirmationNumber is NULL THEN ConfirmationNumber
 ELSE '%' + @ConfirmationNumber + '%' END )`

When the parameter is  null the expression (ConfirmationNumber = ConfirmationNumber) will evaluate which is always true .